# Using sudo with Python script

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I'm trying to write a small script to mount a VirtualBox shared folder each time I execute the script. I want to do it with Python, because I'm trying to learn it for scripting.

The problem is that I need privileges to launch mount command. I could run the script as sudo, but I prefer it to make sudo by its own.

I already know that it is not safe to write your password into a .py file, but we are talking about a virtual machine that is not critical at all: I just want to click the .py script and get it working.

This is my attempt:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

sudoPassword = 'mypass'
command = 'mount -t vboxsf myfolder /home/myuser/myfolder'

subprocess.Popen('sudo -S' , shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
subprocess.Popen(sudoPassword , shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
subprocess.Popen(command , shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

My python version is 2.6

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: @mensi yes, that I am practising to learn using python for these kind of purpose

Comment: you need to pass the password over stdin, see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/165662/894872

Comment: If you don't know what you are doing, **avoid** `shell=True`.  If you can't make things work without it, learn what it does and how it works (and then usually you can).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [running a command as a super user from a python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567542/running-a-command-as-a-super-user-from-a-python-script)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
sudoPassword = 'mypass'
command = 'mount -t vboxsf myfolder /home/myuser/myfolder'
p = os.system('echo %s|sudo -S %s' % (sudoPassword, command))
```

Try this and let me know if it works. :-)

And this one:

`os.popen("sudo -S %s"%(command), 'w').write('mypass')`

Comment: This was my first attempt when I googled it, but doesn't work: it asks me for password at console instead of entering sudoPassword value directly

Comment: @RomanRdgz echo %s converts it to stdin and pipes the output of sudoPassword to sudo command's stdin. Hence it should work(and does work here)

Comment: I imported os, then copy-pasted, and it doesn't work: keeps asking for password. In fact, If i wait and not write anything when asked, output looks like code tried to input password 3 times wrong, saying 3 times 'Sorry, try again'

Comment: Same result, but password attempts get wrong directly, without any wait

Comment: what is written is variable sudoPassword. It is composed by 6 lowercase letters. Nothing weird

Comment: @Roman Rdgz: this puts the password into the command line that might be visible to other users. You could [write directly to subprocess' stdin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23692520/4279) without running the shell

Comment: You really should NEVER use such a line `os.system('echo %s|sudo -S %s' % (sudoPassword, command))`, cause it brings a security hole. By writing your password as shell command, it becomes accessible through `.bash_history` file and by running `history` shell command. Always pass password through stdin as it's more secure approach

Comment: This answer has 3 downvotes, and I'm piling up another one. **This code adds TWO vulnerabilities**: 1) recording the password in the process table which any other process can see, as said above, but also 2) **shell injection**, what if something else can set that password, and sets it to `foo$(rm -rf /*)bar` ? Do you see the problem with that.

Comment: @ulidtko please suggest an alternative then.

Comment: @AniketInge `subprocess.Popen` is the answer, as below from @jfs. If you edit  the two vulnerabilities and [the link](/questions/13045593/using-sudo-with-python-script/23692520#23692520) into your answer — I'll happily take away that downvote :)

Comment: This would be a bad approach i feel. Never store a password open endedly.

Comment: Those saying this is a bad approach: yes it is. However, we never know the real reason why OP is asking this question. May be he's just trying something out on his personal laptop.. or trying to learn something. There was a question, and there is an answer. I am sure OP wouldn't use it in a production environment of a bank or highly secured military server.

Comment: @AniketInge, I absolutely agree! Those annoying security hurdles being annoying in irrelevant contexts ("permission denied" to my own files, hehehe) are indeed super annoying. But you have to recognize: **you have no idea** how wildly diverse are contexts in which code snippets from SO get used. Some of them are very relevant! You've just agreed yourself: it is a bad approach. Immediately next, there're better ways *using which you sacrifice nothing*, but gain security. Why not mention this in the answer? Just for those poor copy-paste hunters who ignore other answers and comment sections.

Comment: @thodnev IF you place a leading space before the command, it will not be saved to the bash history

Answer (score 89):

Many answers focus on how to make your solution work, while very few suggest that *your solution is a **very bad** approach*. If you really want to "practice to learn", why not practice using good solutions? Hardcoding your password is learning the *wrong* approach!

If what you really want is a password-less `mount` for that volume, maybe `sudo` isn't needed *at all*! So may I suggest other approaches?

- Use `/etc/fstab` as [mensi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/871665/mensi) suggested. Use options `user` and `noauto` to let regular users mount that volume.
- Use `Polkit` for passwordless actions: Configure a `.policy` file for your script with `<allow_any>yes</allow_any>` and drop at `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions`
- Edit `/etc/sudoers` to allow your user to use `sudo` without typing your password. As @Anders suggested, you can restrict such usage to specific commands, thus avoiding unlimited passwordless root priviledges in your account. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/155827/42796) for more details on `/etc/sudoers`.

All the above allow passwordless root privilege, none require you to hardcode your password. Choose any approach and I can explain it in more detail.

As for *why* it is a very bad idea to hardcode passwords, here are a few good links for further reading:

- [Why You Shouldn’t Hard Code Your Passwords When Programming](http://www.security-faqs.com/why-you-shouldnt-hard-code-your-passwords-when-programming.html)
- [How to keep secrets secret
  (Alternatives to Hardcoding Passwords)](https://security.web.cern.ch/security/recommendations/en/password_alternatives.shtml)
- [What's more secure? Hard coding credentials or storing them in a database?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/92465)
- [Use of hard-coded credentials, a dangerous programming error: CWE](https://blogs.manageengine.com/it-security/passwordmanagerpro/2010/02/17/use-of-hard-coded-credentials-a-dangerous-programming-error-cwe.html)
- [Hard-coded passwords remain a key security flaw](https://www.csoonline.com/article/3038302/application-development/hard-coded-passwords-remain-a-key-security-flaw.html)

Comment: The last point, edit sudoers is very well explained at https://askubuntu.com/a/155827/42796

Comment: It might helpful for newcomers for you to explain _why_ hardcoding the user's password is a _very bad approach_.

Comment: @pdoherty926: I assumed it was obvious for security reasons, but you're right, might be a good idea to educate on _why_. This goes a little beyond the scope of this answer, so I'll edit it to add a few links for further reading.

Comment: Regarding the suggestion to use passwordless sudo: Hard-coding the password is bad, but adding the user to `/etc/sudoers` is almost as bad! In both cases any attacker that has access to the user account will have root access, too.

Comment: @balu realize that when you add a user to `/etc/sudoers`, you can restrict it to certain commands and use various other controls. Adding a user to `/etc/sudoers` does *not* necessarily enable root access. Although for simple mount of volumes, purpose built tools like `/etc/fstab` are better of course.

Comment: @Anders Good point! Though I'd argue, once you allow executing even just *some* commands as root, you've widened the attack surface by orders of magnitude. (The commands might allow arbitrary code execution, they might change over time…) Anyway, I'm not saying it's impossible to provide decent security guarantees; my intention was just to point out that the standard `sudo` solution that's being recommended in many places is not as secure as people might think and there are many pitfalls. (@MestreLion: Thanks for updating your answer accordingly!)

Comment: Very true, @balu, and good points. But let's not forget the operation the OP wants is to simply  _mount a volume_, and for such common use-case there are better solutions than `/etc/sudoers`. Mount options such as `user` and `noauto` in `/etc/fstab` is almost certainly a better approach security-wise, that's why I listed it first. `/etc/sudoers` is a more general (and less secure) approach better suited to other tasks.

Answer (score 21):

To pass the password to `sudo`'s stdin:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

sudo_password = 'mypass'
command = 'mount -t vboxsf myfolder /home/myuser/myfolder'.split()

p = Popen(['sudo', '-S'] + command, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,
          universal_newlines=True)
sudo_prompt = p.communicate(sudo_password + '\n')[1]
```

Note: you could probably configure passwordless sudo or `SUDO_ASKPASS` command instead of hardcoding your password in the source code.

Comment: the Popen you describe throws an error `can only concatenate list (not “str”) to list` I changed it to `Popen(['sudo -S ' + command]` - That worked for me. It seems that at the time of answer this added to a list implicitly.. which is no longer allowed? or supported..

Comment: @ppumkin wrong. Look at the code in the answer. It has `.split()`. Compare with  your code.

Comment: Ohh boy yes. I missed the split() on the end.. wow late night coding. I slept on it and decided it was a bad idea to do it like this any way so going the passwordless route instead :D I just wanted something to work and was desperate

Comment: How would you solve multiple commands via sudo efficiently?
I want to do these commands in this order:
```
sudo mkdir Filestore
sudo mount [filestore-info] Filestore
sudo chmod 777 Filestore
```
Basically 3 sudo commands

Answer (score 5):

- Use -S option in the sudo command which tells to read the password from 'stdin' instead of the  terminal device.
- Tell Popen to read stdin from PIPE.
- Send the Password to the stdin PIPE of the process by using it as an argument to communicate method. Do not forget to add a new line character, '\n', at the end of the password.

```py
sp = Popen(cmd , shell=True, stdin=PIPE)
out, err = sp.communicate(_user_pass+'\n')
```

Answer (score 4):

`subprocess.Popen` creates a process and opens pipes and stuff. What you are doing is:

- Start a process `sudo -S`
- Start a process `mypass`
- Start a process `mount -t vboxsf myfolder /home/myuser/myfolder`

which is obviously not going to work. You need to pass the arguments to Popen. If you look at [its documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor), you will notice that the first argument is actually a list of the arguments.

Comment: Ok, I get what I'm doing wrong, but I don't think it is possible to pass sudo's password as an argument here with subprocess.Popen(['sudo', '-S', password, command], shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE). SO how can I do it?

Comment: Have a look at the linked SO question

Answer (score 2):

I used this for python 3.5. I did it using **[subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)** module.Using the password like this is very **insecure**.

The [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module takes command as a list of strings so either create a list beforehand using **split()** or pass the whole list later. Read the documentation for moreinformation.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

sudoPassword = 'mypass'
command = 'mount -t vboxsf myfolder /home/myuser/myfolder'.split()

cmd1 = subprocess.Popen(['echo',sudoPassword], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
cmd2 = subprocess.Popen(['sudo','-S'] + command, stdin=cmd1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

output = cmd2.stdout.read.decode()
```

Answer (score 1):

sometimes require a carriage return:

```
os.popen("sudo -S %s"%(command), 'w').write('mypass\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try module pexpect. Here is my code:

```
import pexpect
remove = pexpect.spawn('sudo dpkg --purge mytool.deb')
remove.logfile = open('log/expect-uninstall-deb.log', 'w')
remove.logfile.write('try to dpkg --purge mytool\n')
if remove.expect(['(?i)password.*']) == 0:
    # print "successfull"
    remove.sendline('mypassword')
    time.sleep(2)
    remove.expect(pexpect.EOF,5)
else:
    raise AssertionError("Fail to Uninstall deb package !")
```

Answer (score 1):

To limit what you run as sudo, you could run

```
python non_sudo_stuff.py
sudo -E python -c "import os; os.system('sudo echo 1')"
```

without needing to store the password. The `-E` parameter passes your current user's env to the process. Note that your shell will have sudo priveleges after the second command, so use with caution!

Answer (score 0):

I know it is always preferred not to hardcode the sudo password in the script. However, for some reason, if you have no permission to modify `/etc/sudoers` or change file owner, Pexpect is a feasible alternative.

Here is a Python function `sudo_exec` for your reference:

```python
import platform, os, logging
import subprocess, pexpect

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def sudo_exec(cmdline, passwd):
    osname = platform.system()
    if osname == 'Linux':
        prompt = r'\[sudo\] password for %s: ' % os.environ['USER']
    elif osname == 'Darwin':
        prompt = 'Password:'
    else:
        assert False, osname

    child = pexpect.spawn(cmdline)
    idx = child.expect([prompt, pexpect.EOF], 3)
    if idx == 0: # if prompted for the sudo password
        log.debug('sudo password was asked.')
        child.sendline(passwd)
        child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
return child.before
```

Answer (score 0):

It works in python 2.7 and 3.8:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from shlex import split

proc = Popen(split('sudo -S %s' % command), bufsize=0, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
proc.stdin.write((password +'\n').encode()) # write as bytes
proc.stdin.flush() # need if not bufsize=0 (unbuffered stdin)
```

without `.flush()` password will not reach `sudo` if stdin buffered.
In python 2.7 `Popen` by default used `bufsize=0` and `stdin.flush()` was not needed.

For secure using, create password file in protected directory:

```
mkdir --mode=700 ~/.prot_dir
nano ~/.prot_dir/passwd.txt
chmod 600 ~/.prot_dir/passwd.txt
```

at start your py-script read password from ~/.prot_dir/passwd.txt

```
with open(os.environ['HOME'] +'/.prot_dir/passwd.txt') as f:
    password = f.readline().rstrip()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os 
os.system("echo TYPE_YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE | sudo -S TYPE_YOUR_LINUX_COMMAND")
```

**Open your ide and run the above code. Please change TYPE_YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE and TYPE_YOUR_LINUX_COMMAND to your linux admin password and your desired linux command after that run your python script. Your output will show on terminal. Happy Coding :)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SSHScript](https://iapyeh.github.io/sshscript/index) . Below are example codes:

```
## filename: example.spy 
sudoPassword = 'mypass'
command = 'mount -t vboxsf myfolder /home/myuser/myfolder'
$$echo @{sudoPassword} | sudo -S @{command}
```

or, simply one line (almost the same as running on console)

```
## filename: example.spy 
$$echo mypass | sudo -S mount -t vboxsf myfolder /home/myuser/myfolder
```

Then, run it on console

```
sshscript example.spy
```

Where "sshscript" is the CLI of SSHScript (installed by pip).

Answer (score 0):

solution im going with,because password in plain txt in an env file on dev pc is ok, and variable in the  repo and gitlab runner is masked.

use .dotenv  put pass in .env on local machine, DONT COMMIT .env to git.
add same var in gitlab variable

.env file has:
PASSWORD=superpass

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

subprocess.run(f'echo {os.getenv("PASSWORD")} | sudo -S rm  /home//folder/filetodelete_created_as_root.txt', shell=True, check=True)
```

this works  locally and in gitlab. no plain password is committed to repo.

yes,  you can argue  running a sudo command w shell true is kind of crazy, but if you have files written to host from a docker  w root, and you need to pro-grammatically  delete them, this is functional.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).