# python Popen chmod error starting Postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, popen

I can run:

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

from the command line with no issues. However when I try running the following:

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE

pwd = getsudopwd()
cmd = ['sudo','service',process,'state']
p = Popen(cmd,stdout=PIPE,stdin=PIPE,stderr=PIPE,universal_newlines=True)
out,err = p.communicate(pwd+'\n')
if err: raise RuntimeError(err)
```

I get the following error

chmod: changing permissions of '/var/run/postgresql': Operation not permitted. So, why is there is an error accessing the pid directory for postgresql when this is run from Python?

Comment: I tried this on OSX and Trusty, and it worked fine. I couldn't supply password the way you want it, but you should be able to run echo "mypasswd" | sudo -S command. The -S option will force sudo to read passwd from the stdin.

Comment: @Boris, you cannot do that without using shell=True,.

Comment: He should be able to create another process (for example, echo process) and set the stdin of the sudo process to echo.stdout.

Comment: @Boris, it will work just fine without

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yeah, that should work fine also.

Comment: related: [Using sudo with Python script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24257940/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `-S` with sudo:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import getpass

pwd = getpass.getpass()
proc = Popen(['sudo', '-S', 'service',process,'state'],
             stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,universal_newlines=True)
out,err= proc.communicate(input="{}\n".format(pwd))
```

Comment: you should leave `stdout`, `stderr` separate: `stderr=PIPE` as in the question (`sudo` writes the prompt to stderr with the `--stdin` option, the child process might right to stdout something useful).

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you use the [`sh`](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/) library

its very simple and easy to use

```
from sh import sudo
print sudo('service postgresql start')
```

Comment: how does it help to pass the sudo password available in `pwd` variable?

Answer (score 0):

Running sudo command with the -S option and piping your password to the stdin of the sudo command should solve your problem.

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

echo = Popen(('echo', 'mypasswd'), stdout = PIPE)
p = Popen(['sudo', '-S', 'service', 'postgresql', 'restart'], stdin = echo.stdout, stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE, universal_newlines = True)
out, err = p.communicate()
print out
```