# change date/time using python in linux

Tags: python, linux, date, time

I tried using `date` command to change the system time in debian linux:

`os.system("echo passwd | "sudo date -s \"Thu Aug  9 21:31:26 UTC 2012\")`

and I set the python file permission to `777` and also `chown` as `root`. But it does not work and says `date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted`. Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: It did not give me any problems (I executed it normally). Try running .py with sudo. In my case, permissions are == -rw-r--r--

Comment: Your quoting is wrong, try: os.system("echo passwd | 'sudo date -s \"Thu Aug  9 21:31:26 UTC 2012\"'")

Comment: @cdarke, when I use sudo it works. But I want to run it without writing sudo.

Comment: That isn't what your question asks, and that is nothing to do with Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sudo doesn't take password from stdin, but from the terminal device.

Add your `date` to the sudoers file so you can run it as root without a password.  man sudoers.

```
bob     ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/date
```

Next, use subprocess instead of os.system.

```
sudodate = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "date", "-s", "Thu Aug  9 21:31:26 UTC 2012"])
sudodate.communicate()
```

Comment: You can [pass the password to `sudo` via stdin if you must](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23692520/4279) but updating `sudoers` (creating `/etc/sudoers.d/date`) is a better option in most cases. Don't use `.communicate()` unless some of the standard streams are redirected (using `PIPE`). Use `subprocess.check_call()` instead. To hide the output of a subprocess, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11269575/4279)

Comment: @ChadMiller, Thanks for your comment. I learned a lot ;), However before I see your comment, I tried making another python file and I addressed `os.system("echo passwd | sudo -S python file.py")` and run without `sudo`. It worked 0_o . Isn't it a little bit strange?!

Comment: Note: even with **NOPASSWD**, you still must use **SUDO** in front of command

Answer (score 1):

You did a lower case -s it is meant to be -S so that is why it isn't working.

Comment: My Ubuntu 16.04 bash lists `date -s` for STRING entry.

Comment: My Debian 11.1 bash lists `date -s` for STRING entry