# Python emulate apt-key

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to use python to automate some admin scripts. For example:

```
wget --output-document=- https://www.monetdb.org/downloads/MonetDB-GPG-KEY | sudo apt-key add -
```

I tried:

```
subprocess.call
```

But it has an error with the '|' arg

Comment: related: [How do I use subprocess.Popen to connect multiple processes by pipes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/295459/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian's link is great and it would be reasonable to dup this question. But as a matter of form, you really need to show us _how_ you used `subprocess.call`. The stackoverflow surveilance system is down so we are not able to look over your shoulder right now.

Comment: You may have problems with the `sudo` password. If you need to pass in a password [Using sudo with Python script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045593/using-sudo-with-python-script) may help.

Comment: Solved issue by related topic. Thanks!