# How to make my script automatically type my admin password into Mac OS terminal?

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I have a Mac and I'm programming a sort of security script (I know it's useless and overkill but I'm just trying to expand my knowledge of Python) and one of the steps in my script requires a password from the admin before it can execute.

I want to make it so this script will execute under certain circumstances and I don't want it to require any human interaction. I've tried doing the following:

```
os.system("sudo -s")            
os.system("my password")
```

However, it tells me that I typed the password wrong (clearly Apple made it so you can't have a program type it).

In short, I've tried everything. I then figured out that you can copy and paste the password and it works. So my question is: how can I have my script copy and paste the password and then hit enter? Alternatively, is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using sudo with Python script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045593/using-sudo-with-python-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to have a capital "-S", so it should look like:

```
p = os.system('echo {}|sudo -S {}'.format('my password', 'command to run'))
```

By the way, the reason for you not to do this is less about how you can mess up your computer using `sudo` and more about how you are going to have a script on your computer with your sudo password stored in plain text.

Comment: Michael is there any way to ask for password with system dialog by script and get the result in the script?