# Clear memory cache from python

Tags: python, shell, caching, psql, timescaledb

I am using python because i try to run some queries from psql in cold state in a for loop.So before the execution of every query my cache must be clear!
I imported os and then i did this:

```
if state=="cold":
         os.system('sudo sh -c "sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"')
```

I am getting this output:

```
sh: 1: cannot create /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied

sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
```

I dont know how to fix this.

Comment: sudo requires to enter the password manually. you cant enter from your code unless you use -S option. try -S option

Comment: and you get permission denied because you didnt enter password from sudo prompt and basically that wasnt sudo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

acorrding to this stack question:

[how to pass sudo password from python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045593/using-sudo-with-python-script)

you can try this:

```
password = 'my sudo password'
command = 'sh -c "sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"'

# formatting the sudo password and the command
shell_script = f"echo {password} | sudo -S {command}"

# running the script
os.system(shell_script)
```