# Enter Password automatically for Sudo in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, sudo, os.system

I want to enter the password automatically for a Password Request by Sudo in this line :-

```
os.system("sudo -S shutdown -r")
```

Comment: duplicated?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13045700/7625386

Comment: You should consider configuring private key authentication for SSH.