# Inputting password for sudo command via python script

Tags: python, applescript, sudo

Bit of a strange one. I have a python file that is activated by an AppleScript.
My python script does a couple of basic commands. One thing it does is try and run a sudo command in a terminal window.
My problem is that a sudo command needs a password to be executed. I can't figure out how to enter my password in the python file, as the code wants a password input for in order to execute the sudo command.

The apple script below calls a python script known as `setting_pm.py` to be run from my desktop folder.

**Apple script:**

```
set desktop_folder to "$HOME/Desktop"
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "cd desktop;cd setting_pm;python3 setting_pm.py"
end tell
```

**Python file:**

```
os.system("sudo pmset schedule cancelall")
os.system("myPassword")
```

If you test the code above you will see that the password gets asked for but it wont seem to accept the next command where i try and input my password.

I have played around with removing passwords from sudo but i like the idea of having passwords enabled, and only entering the password in this specific situation from a python script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using sudo with Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045593/using-sudo-with-python-script)

Comment: had a look there but it didn't seem to do it. thanks though. i got it:

Answer (score 3):

answer:

```
import os
os.system("echo password | sudo -S pmset schedule cancelall")
```