# Run external applications using Python and call their methods inside

Tags: python, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Wish You all beautiful sunny day! :D,

I have a question for You guys. I have following python "script":

```
import os    
os.system('ubuntu.exe')
```

Which opens Ubuntu running on my WSL. And now, when the Ubuntu terminal appears:
[image: Ubuntu terminal using WSL]
I would like to execute following commands: ***sudo /etc/init.d/dbus start*** and ***sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp start*** using my python script (just do them automatically). However, when I run one of the commands above, terminal requests my password:
[image: Terminal wants me to enter password]
So the script should be also able to enter the password.
Is there any way, how to do it?

Kind regards,
D.

Comment: Maybe helpful or related: [Using sudo with Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045593/using-sudo-with-python-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the [question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13045593/11810933) linked in the comments is a good read (`sudoers` in particular), there's a better method for WSL.  Instead of using `ubuntu.exe`, use the newer `wsl.exe` replacement.  The `wsl` command offers more control over the startup, including being able to change the user:

```
import os    
os.system('wsl ~ -u root -e sh -c "nohup service xrdp start"')
os.system('wsl -u root service dbus start')
```

The `nohup` is needed because of what seems to be a timing issue.  When starting up via the WSL command, the shell (owning process) will terminate before `xrdp` gets a chance to fork.  `nohup` just makes sure that the full `xrdp` init script gets a chance to run before that happens.  This really isn't a WSL issue, per se.  It can also be replicated if you were do something similar with `exec sh -c "sudo service xrdp start"`.

A couple of other notes.  First, this does not require a password, since WSL doesn't have the concept of "login."  The `/init` process (WSL's PID1 and initialization) is responsible for setting the owning user for each session.  This is not considered a security risk since even the root WSL user runs with no greater than the permissions of the *Windows* user.

Also note that, in my experience, it's not necessary to start `dbus` for `xrdp` access, even though I've seen instructions that say it is.  Ultimately it will depend on what you want to run within the `xrdp` session, of course.

Comment: Thanks :D, however not sure if it works...when I run the script it says "Starting Remote Desktop Protocol server [OK]" so no problem though, but connecting to Ubuntu using windows remote doesn´t work. To make it work I need to manually start Ubuntu using WSL and type the commands above.

Comment: @Dandys Oh, that sounds really familiar.  I know we came across this in another question on one of the Stack sites.  Let me find it.  Fairly sure the answer is going to be obvious to me when I find it.

Comment: @Dandys Well, I found the issue, but now that I remember it, it is so far from obvious.  There's a workaround, but it's not my favorite, by any stretch.  Edited into my answer.

Comment: @Dandys And then came up with a much better workaround than the first time I tried this.  Edited again.