# How to write the Raspberry Pi's autostart directory using python?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi4, autostart, raspbian-buster

I am using Raspberry Pi4 Model B with buster os in it. I am trying to write a python script for running the webpage at bootup. On entering **sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart** in the terminal and adding **@chromium-browser --start-fullscreen --start-maximized https://teams.microsoft.com/** at the last line I can see the webpage at boot. But the problem is I need to do this with a python program. Have tried many scripts and it's not working. Every time It's throwing the error saying **"No such file or directory: sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart"**. I am attaching the script below. Please help me in solving this I am new to Raspberry Pi.

#### Without adding sudo nano

conf_file = /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

```
def update_url():
       conf_file= '/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart'
       try:
          with open(conf_file, 'w')as file:
             file.write('@chromium-browser --start-fullscreen --start-maximized https://teams.microsoft.com/')

       except Exception as ex:
          print("Cant write dirctory:",ex)
          return 0
       finally:
           pass
```

Output:

`permission denied: /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`

#### Adding sudo nano

conf_file = sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

```
def update_url():
       conf_file= 'sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart'
       try:
          with open(conf_file, 'w')as file:
             file.write('@chromium-browser --start-fullscreen --start-maximized https://teams.microsoft.com/')

       except Exception as ex:
          print("Cant write dirctory:",ex)
          return 0
       finally:
           pass
```

Output:

`No such file or directory: sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`

Comment: You need to run you .py with sudo, like `sudo python my-test.py`

Comment: @Philippe . Actually I have developed a web form for receiving the web url as the input from user .I am saving that user input into a variable named Value1. Like this --> Value1 = form.get('url') . After that I'm trying to open the autostart directory using python itself and write the received user input into it like this --> (f'@chromium-browser --start-fullscreen http:\\{Value1}\') . As you said above I tried putting this flask application in crontab for executing at boot . But I can't get the output .

Answer (score 0):

I have a hunch that Python thinks that "sudo nano" is a directory. Maybe attempt to make it run in the terminal. Read this: [Using sudo with Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045593/using-sudo-with-python-script)

Comment: Thank for your reply. Sure I will try it.