# Executing sudo command with space through python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi guys and gal's I have a problem.

I'm executing a python script that needs to run a sudo command to continue. This is the command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/test restart
```

The issue is that no matter how I execute this it only runs sudo and /etc/init.d/test and returns:

```
sudo: /etc/init.d/test: command not found
```

The issue seems to be that restart is not sent along with the command.

These are the ways I've tried running the command:

Attempt 1 using os

```
os.system('sudo /etc/init.d/test restart')
```

Attempt 2 using subprocess

```
x = subprocess.Popen(['sudo','/etc/init.d/test','restart'])
x.communicate()
```

Attempt 3 using subprocess again

```
x = subprocess.Popen(['sudo','/etc/init.d/test restart'])
x.communicate()
```

This actually returned:

```
sudo: /etc/init.d/test restart: command not found
```

Which doesn't make sense since if I execute the command directly on the system it works.
Any ideas as to how I could do this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567542/running-a-command-as-a-super-user-from-a-python-script ?

Comment: Pretty much but the answer given there did not work for me. As you can see the full path is given and it still does not work :( Should I have asked the question again in that thread? If so I'm sorry I thought since it did not answer me I could just ask again.

Comment: The sudo command will give you root privileges, and needs your password to do so. It's a really, really bad idea to give root access without a password

Comment: This will work on a bunch of machines with different passwords so I figured it would be best if I just left it to the user to input the password.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess,getpass
password = getpass.getpass()
#proc = subprocess.Popen(
#  ['sudo','-p','','-S','/etc/init.d/test','restart'],
#   stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    ['sudo','-p','','-S','echo','restart'],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.stdin.write(password+'\n')
proc.stdin.close()
proc.wait()
```

Comment: When I execute this nothing happens and after a bit the script continues. Now since this should restart the system I'm not sure whether it worked or not. Is it suppose to be just a blank screen or could there be an error?

Comment: The script just prompts for a password and prints the word 'restart'. I tried it and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this:

```
sudo: /etc/init.d/test: command not found
```

it indicates that /etc/init.d/test doesn't exist.  Try it yourself like this from the command line:

```
> sudo blarg whatever whatever
sudo: blarg: command not found
```

So just make sure that the command you are trying to execute really exists:

```
ls -l /etc/init.d/test
```

If you still have problems, then try to simplify things by first just getting it to execute 'sudo whoami' -- once you get that working, change it to your "real" command.

Comment: Yeah but see I only get that because it doesn't run the full command /etc/init.d/test restart. If I were to run the full command in the linux console it works. Thanks for the help though.