# how to execute shell command from python

Tags: python, shell, command

how can I execute the following command in python please

```
sudo mount --bind /media/networkshare/camera /var/www/media
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically you could use Python's subprocess module for this (see also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567542/running-a-command-as-a-super-user-from-a-python-script)):

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(['sudo', 'mount', '--bind', '/media/networkshare/camera', 
                  '/var/www/media'])
```

Of course, this will still prompt you for your password. If you don't want it to prompt for a password, then you'll have to setup `sudo` so that it can execute a single command as root. See the following guide for how to do that:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/155791/how-do-i-sudo-a-command-in-a-script-without-being-asked-for-a-password

Comment: you should probably use `check_call()` instead of `Popen`. `Popen` doesn't wait for the child process to finish.

Comment: True. You could just use `subprocess.call` too. I went ahead and updated my answer to use `check_call` as it seems better.