# open terminal with sudo python

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I have to open a terminal using `sudo` from python. Consider my password is `pass` and I need to run a command within script which is `sudo critical-stack-intel pull`.

I have following small piece of code:

```
import subprocess
import shlex

command = "sudo critical-stack-intel pull"
popen = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command),stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
popen.communicate("pass")
popen.wait()
# print help(p)
```

If i run the file as `python myfile.py`, it asks me for password within terminal. This is not what I desire. I want the python to handle the password I gave and run normally. How do I get this done?

**EDIT**

Using `popen.communicate(pass + "\n")` along with `sudo -S` did what i desired.

Comment: `sudo` opens the tty, it does not use stdin by default. Use `sudo -S` instead

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567542/running-a-command-as-a-super-user-from-a-python-script

Comment: I want to use `subprocess.Popen` not `os.Popen`.

Comment: The accepted answer there is not the best answer, unfortunately; but the question is a duplicate, and you'll find good answers there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-S` option of `sudo` to pass the password via stdin. Most likely, though, it's a better idea to allow sudo access to `critical-stack-intel` without password using `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: Fixing this in `/etc/sudoers` seems like the right approach. Check out [command aliasses](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers#Command_Aliases)

Comment: I used `-S` in my command along with `popen.communicate(pass)` but its not ending the session.

Comment: @SarvagyaPant: IIRC `communicate()` does not close stdin. You need to send a newline character together with your password

Comment: @mrks can you update the answer suggesting to use `pass + "\n"` in my code.

Comment: Actually I was wrong: all streams are closed by `communicate()`

Comment: @SarvagyaPant: You can suggest edits to answers yourself :)

Comment: @sarvagyaPant, I was trying same code, but I want to also print stdout output, but that gives error as I/O operation on closed file, looks like after stdin to pass password to closes pipe  
import subprocess
pass="123"
popen = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "-S", "dmesg", ],stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
popen.communicate(pass+"\n")
popen.wait()
print popen.communicate()