# Running subprocess.run as root not working

Tags: python, subprocess, sudo, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to kill a subprocess via its pid by using subprocess.call() to do it. I obtain the pid by assigning return to a value like this:

```
return = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "scrolling-text-example", "-y7"]) 
x= return.pid
```

When when I am ready to end this subprocess I am using this code:

```
subprocess.call(["sudo","kill",str(x)])
```

This does not kill the subprocess, but if I open terminal (let's say x is 1234),  and type: `sudo kill 1234` , it will kill the subprocess.

Comment: As I know, you're supposed to do `sudo kill -9 1234'

Comment: Getting close --  but now the error says **"FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sudo kill 1853': 'sudo kill -9 1853'**

Comment: I think it doesn't consider `str(x)` as a string.

Comment: Actually I changed it to `killCmd = "sudo kill %s" %x` then 
    `subprocess.run(killCmd)` to check this and I am getting the same message

Comment: Try `x = str(return.pid)`

Comment: I did that-- `x = str(return.pid)`  and running `subprocess.call(["sudo","kill",x])`does nothing -- I think I need root privileges on this folder that I am working in -- I am looking into how to do that now..

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567542/running-a-command-as-a-super-user-from-a-python-script).

Answer (score 0):

Use `x = str(return pid)` and `subprocess.call(["sudo","kill","-9",x])` and then try to grant root privileges. And, this allows to turn the process number to a string *before* calling the subprocess. Also, as I mentioned, use `-9` (or `-15` if you prefer using that). (Try to kill 1014 process too).

Comment: Unfortuantely this did not work -- However I did a `ps -e --forest` to view the relationship  and got this :`1009 ?        00:00:00                  |   \_ sudo
 1014 ?        00:00:04                  |       \_ scrolling-text-` So there are two processes started by this -- It appears the **scrolling-text-** process is a child of the **sudo** process that is the one that returns x, which is 1009

Comment: **UPDATE** -- I find that this code does kill the 1009 process, but not the 1014 process -- so I need to kill BOTH as 1014 is dependent

Answer (score 0):

I found that the main process I identify with `x = return.pid` actually runs a child process which is the one I needed to kill, so from the parent process identified, we need to kill a child processes. The addition of "-P" includes child processes in this situation.
The following command structure is what I needed:

```
subprocess.call(["sudo","pkill","-9","-P",x])
```